# PC inspiron 1525 won't boot after upgrading CPU to T8300

Tags: cpu, upgrade

My PC inspiron 1525 does not boot ater I changed CPU to T8300 and updated BIOS to A17,I upgraded RAM to 4GB.However it boots with the old CPU T4200.Anyone has suggestion to resolve this problem.

Comment: Either your BIOS does not recognize the CPU or the CPU is dead. In general, laptop vendors don't expect users to upgrade their CPU's, so there's very little need to recognize CPU's beyond their offerings.

Comment: Define "does not boot" in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The T8300 and the T4200 are quite different in many aspects although they are based on the same architecture.

The T8300 was released much earlier than the T4200 in the market. The T8300 is clocked at a much higher frequency 2.4 GHz vs. 2.0 GHz of that of the T4200 and has a much larger Cache size of 3 MB compared to 1 MB of T4200. Other than this the T8300 supports Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) and Idle Sates. So there is a significant difference between the two processors both in terms of power and features. You can get the detailed comparison [here.](http://ark.intel.com/compare/37251,33099)

Laptop manufactures are most likely to customize the BIOS of their laptops to support a particular series of processors instead of the entire family. So its natural that the BIOS is most likely not recognizing the new processor as it is not supported by it.

If you would install a T4400 or any other model of processor from the T4xxx series line up, the BIOS might recognize it. But this depends on what Dell has done with the BIOS as pointed out by **geewee** in the comment section. The other possibility is also there that the new processor might be dead.